# accessing objects from other files in go program

Tags: go

The goji microframework for Go [has a fully functional example app with three files](https://github.com/zenazn/goji/blob/master/example/main.go), `main.go, models.go and middleware.go`. I installed the framework using the go get command

```
go get github.com/zenazn/goji
```

and therefore have the example app availabl in my GOPATH like this

```
src/github.com/zenazn/goji/example
```

if I navigate to /example/ and run `go run main.go`, it gives me errors which indicate that the main.go file is isn't accessing the objects from the `middleware.go` and `models.go` files, like this

```
./main.go:39: undefined: PlainText
./main.go:47: undefined: SuperSecure
./main.go:73: undefined: Greets
./main.go:74: undefined: Greets
./main.go:85: undefined: Greet
./main.go:98: undefined: Greets
./main.go:99: undefined: Greets
./main.go:107: undefined: Users
./main.go:116: undefined: Greets
./main.go:116: too many errors
```

There is no code in `main.go` that imports `middleware.go` or `models.go`, only the regular import statements for libraries.

How are these files supposed to be tied together so that the objects from one are available in the other?

from main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/param"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

// Note: the code below cuts a lot of corners to make the example app simple.

func main() {
    // Add routes to the global handler
    goji.Get("/", Root)
    // Fully backwards compatible with net/http's Handlers
    goji.Get("/greets", http.RedirectHandler("/", 301))
    // Use your favorite HTTP verbs
    goji.Post("/greets", NewGreet)
    // Use Sinatra-style patterns in your URLs
    goji.Get("/users/:name", GetUser)
    // Goji also supports regular expressions with named capture groups.
    goji.Get(regexp.MustCompile(`^/greets/(?P<id>\d+)$`), GetGreet)

    // Middleware can be used to inject behavior into your app. The
    // middleware for this application are defined in middleware.go, but you
    // can put them wherever you like.
    goji.Use(PlainText)

    admin := web.New()
    goji.Handle("/admin/*", admin)
    admin.Use(SuperSecure)

    // Goji's routing, like Sinatra's, is exact: no effort is made to
    // normalize trailing slashes.
    goji.Get("/admin", http.RedirectHandler("/admin/", 301))


    admin.Get("/admin/", AdminRoot)
    admin.Get("/admin/finances", AdminFinances)

    // Use a custom 404 handler
    goji.NotFound(NotFound)

    goji.Serve()
}
```

**middleware.go**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

// PlainText sets the content-type of responses to text/plain.
func PlainText(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

// Nobody will ever guess this!
const Password = "admin:admin"

// SuperSecure is HTTP Basic Auth middleware for super-secret admin page. Shhhh!
func SuperSecure(c *web.C, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        auth := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
        if !strings.HasPrefix(auth, "Basic ") {
            pleaseAuth(w)
            return
        }

        password, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(auth[6:])
        if err != nil || string(password) != Password {
            pleaseAuth(w)
            return
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func pleaseAuth(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Gritter"`)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    w.Write([]byte("Go away!\n"))
}
```

**models.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "time"
)

// A Greet is a 140-character micro-blogpost that has no resemblance whatsoever
// to the noise a bird makes.
type Greet struct {
    User    string    `param:"user"`
    Message string    `param:"message"`
    Time    time.Time `param:"time"`
}

// Store all our greets in a big list in memory, because, let's be honest, who's
// actually going to use a service that only allows you to post 140-character
// messages?
var Greets = []Greet{
    {"carl", "Welcome to Gritter!", time.Now()},
    {"alice", "Wanna know a secret?", time.Now()},
    {"bob", "Okay!", time.Now()},
    {"eve", "I'm listening...", time.Now()},
}

// Write out a representation of the greet
func (g Greet) Write(w io.Writer) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n@%s at %s\n---\n", g.Message, g.User,
        g.Time.Format(time.UnixDate))
}

// A User is a person. It may even be someone you know. Or a rabbit. Hard to say
// from here.
type User struct {
    Name, Bio string
}

// All the users we know about! There aren't very many...
var Users = map[string]User{
    "alice": {"Alice in Wonderland", "Eating mushrooms"},
    "bob":   {"Bob the Builder", "Making children dumber"},
    "carl":  {"Carl Jackson", "Duct tape aficionado"},
}

// Write out the user
func (u User) Write(w io.Writer, handle string) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s (@%s)\n%s\n", u.Name, handle, u.Bio)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `go run` or `go run *.go` you are running/compiling only main.go the other files are not included.

Comment: Thanks, but please clarify something.  How come with this project `https://github.com/mantishK/gonotevanilla`, for example, you run it by only running the `main.go` file . the readme says `go run github.com/mantishK/gonotevanilla/main.go` There are so many other files in this project, why does only the `main.go` file in that project need to be run, but, as you say in your answer, every file in this project (i.e. the project linked to in the OP) need to be compiled. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: because that main.go is importing "github.com/mantishK/gonotevanilla/controllers" as a library. if you go inside those files you will notice that the package is not 'main' but a different one

Answer (score 0):

You should, preferably, be using `go build` - to build a binary which you can then run as `./example`.

Go operates on packages, not files, and `go run` is ultimately just a convenience to be used when testing examples or simple programs (it builds the binary and discards it, effectively).